# How to type the where argument in find operation when querying using Mikro-ORM?

Tags: typescript, graphql, mikro-orm

I am creating a GraphQL server using Mikro-ORM and type-graphql and for certain GraphQL queries, I need to dynamically create the "where" argument for find operations depending on the nullity of the arguments to the query. My issue is with regards to the typing of the "where" argument.

```
@Query(() => [Topic])
  topics(
    @Ctx() { em }: Context,
    @Arg("filter") { subject_id, approved }: TopicArgs
  ): Promise<Topic[]> {
    const where: any = {};
    if (approved) where.approved = approved;
    return em.find(Topic, filter);
  }
```

I tried using `FilterQuery<Topic>` based on the call signature of `find` but that raises "Property does not exist on type" errors on the line of assignment and "incompatible types" error on the line with the call to the `find` function. Is there a solution to this other than using `any` like in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the parameters have the right types, You could try something like this to simplify typing issues:

```
@Query(() => [Topic])
  topics(
    @Ctx() { em }: Context,
    @Arg("filter") { subject_id, approved }: TopicArgs
  ): Promise<Topic[]> {
    return em.find(Topic, {
       ...(approved ? { approved } : {}),
       ...(subject_id ? { subject_id } : {})
    });
  }
```

The nice thing is that you can combine more complex conditions, and also provide default queries when a parameter wasn't provided.

If you still want to declare an explicit object for the where filters, you should import the `FilterQuery` type from `mikro-orm`.

Then you should be able to declare it like this:

```
@Query(() => [Topic])
  topics(
    @Ctx() { em }: Context,
    @Arg("filter") { subject_id, approved }: TopicArgs
  ): Promise<Topic[]> {
    const where: FilterQuery<Topic> = {};
    if (approved) where.approved = approved;
    return em.find(Topic, where);
  }
```